# wowza stop record without stopping the post stream(like record pause)

Tags: wowza

I am wondering if there exist a method with which I can stop recording without stopping the post stream? And so I can go on recording without creating a new stream.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have started and configured the recording, you should be able to easily stop the recording and resume it again later through Wowza. If you started the recording through the Manager UI by pressing the record button in the Incoming Streams page, the same page should subsequently show a stop button for a currently running recording. If you started recording through the APIs, there are API call methods to stop the streamRecorder object as well. In order to resume the recording, you will need to ensure that you have configured append mode. If you have configured version or delete mode, then it will create new file recordings or overwrite the recording respectively on each restart.

If you have chosen the option to "Record all streams" in Wowza, this does not provide you with a lot of configuration options. You will need to choose one of the other options above in order to manually stop the recording.